# Linux packages - Separate Python's external libraries from the system

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, python, architecture

I read this [articles](https://hynek.me/articles/virtualenv-lives/) (check *What About Python CLI Tools?*).

Well, this is obivous, separate external Python packages from your System Python's site-packages.
When doing a `sudo apt-get install package` some packages depends on a external Python library, say, [lxml](http://lxml.de/), so therefore, it will install lxml into Python's system site-package and use with the package you installed.

Is this a good approach from a Unix view? Is there in Debian or any other distribution a way to tell the package manager to install the python package it depends on in your virtualenv and use it from there? Is there **ANY** way to separate Python's dependencies from your system?

If there is no way, and still, installing external Python packages to your virtualenv is the correct way, why do we still use the system site-packages?

Ps: [site-packages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use the system site-packages for system wide installs that work together with the python version that comes with the system.

If you want to experiment, either with a particular python version, or with the same version as the system uses, but without polluting the system wide site-packages/dist-packages (under /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/ then you use `virtualenv`.

You cannot easily install `.deb` based python packages in virtualenv, although it is possible by giving an alternate base directory for installing, just like the CD/USB based installer installs packages on your hard disc.
I would not go into that trouble and use [`devpi`](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) to locally cache the python packages that you need from PyPI.